# Convert Varchar Date and Time From Columns To DataTime T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have 2 columns MyDate and MyTime in a MyTable

```
MyDate varchar(8)
Mytime varchar(6)
```

I want to create a datetime of these 2 fields

```
MyDate = '20220306'
MyTime = '171638'
```

The date seems to format by

```
SELECT convert(date, MyDate, 101) FROM MyTable
```

However the Time I cant get right. I have tried the following

```
SELECT convert(time, MyTime, 101) FROM MyTable

SELECT FORMAT(cast(MyTime as datetime),'hh:mm:tt')  FROM MyTable

select CONVERT(varchar(15),MyTime,103)  FROM MyTable
```

I want to get both the Date and Time in one go

Comment: What's the type of `MyDate` and `MyTime`?

Comment: MyDate Varchar(8) and MyTime varchar(6)

Comment: That's a serious bug. `date` and `time` aren't strings and have no formats. Don't store dates as strings. You can *never* be sure about the contents or the format. At best you'll get a conversion error. Worst case, you get the wrong date or time, eg January 4 instead of April 1. There's no if or but about this.

Comment: Your time is not even in the right format.  You have to either enter `:` between hour, min, sec or you do string manipulation.

Comment: The more important question is why would your date and time be varchars?

Comment: This is the situation I was given. I agree dates and times shouldnt be stored as varchars.

Comment: Use `stuff` to put 2 colons in your time string. But also read the comments above and fix your data model.

Comment: No culture or service uses an unseparated time string, so there's no CONVERT style or PARSE culture that can parse this directly. You'll have to inject `:` into the string before you can parse it as a time

Comment: Can I inject the ":" and convert all in 1 go?

Comment: `This is the situation I was given` the fix is to change the types to the correct ones. In this case, the conversion is one-off and using `STUFF` won't be *that* costly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is just to do below.  The better solution is to change the types.

```
SELECT CAST(@MyDate AS DATE)
    , CAST(LEFT(@MyTime, 2) + ':' + SUBSTRING(@MyTime, 3, 2) + ':' + RIGHT(@MyTime, 2) AS TIME)
```

Comment: I added a CONCAT and almost am there returned 2023-03-06 17:16:38.0000000  - How can I get rid of the .0000000?

Comment: @user12847070 That's the precision of `DATETIME2`.  If you use `DATETIME2`, it will always have the 7 decimal places.

Answer (score 1):

make a correct time out of it and convert it

```
DECLARE @MyTime varchar(6)
SET @MyTime = '171638'
SELECT 
  CONVERT(varchar,CONCAT(substring(@MyTime,1,2),':',substring(@MyTime,3,2),':',substring(@MyTime,5,2)) ,8)
```

| (No column name) |
| --- |
| 17:16:38 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xoNAhfg4)

Answer (score 0):

This is another super easy way and it drops the decimal places by using the correct resolution on the DATETIME2 to do so.

```
--===== This uses STUFF to add the colons instead of multiple SUBSTRINGs.
 SELECT MyDateTime = CONVERT(DATETIME2(0),CONCAT(MyDate,' ',STUFF(STUFF(MyTime,5,0,':'),3,0,':')))
   FROM dbo.MyTable
;
```

As a bit of a sidebar, avoid the use of the FORMAT() function on table returns if you value performance.  See the article at the following link for proof of that.  FORMAT is almost 28 times slower than CONVERT for simple things and almost 18 times slower than multiple CONVERTs for the complex stuff.

https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/how-to-format-dates-in-sql-server-hint-dont-use-format